# Flash Write and HardFault Problem

Tags: stm32, flash

I am using stm32f4 and I am trying to write some data on dual bank flash.

I am calling the below function in my code after the clean related bank.

```
  uint32_t totalBlockNumber;
  uint32_t blockNumber;
  uint8_t blockData[512];
  uint32_t frameDataCount;
```

(frameDataCount always > 8)

```
Flash_Write_Start(totalBlockNumber,blockNumber,(frameDataCount - 8), blockData);
```

Than this is the Flash_Write_Start function:

```
void Flash_Write_Start( uint32_t totalBlockNumber, uint32_t blockNumber, uint32_t packet_length, uint8_t * blockData)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef errorCheck = 1;
  uint32_t bankActive;
  if(fwFrameCounter == blockNumber)
  {    
  errorCheck = FLASH_If_Write(Flash_Write_Address, blockData, packet_length);
  }
  if(errorCheck != FLASHIF_OK)
  {
    SerialPrint("FLASH ERROR\n");
}
```

Not every time but I have a hardfault, when code comes in `FLASH_If_Write(Flash_Write_Address, blockData, packet_length);` function. What is the reason?

```
    FLASHIF_StatusTypeDef FLASH_If_Write(uint32_t destination, uint32_t *p_source, uint32_t length)
{
  FLASHIF_StatusTypeDef status ;
  HAL_StatusTypeDef halErrorFlag;
  /* Unlock the Flash to enable the flash control register access *************/
  if (HAL_FLASH_Unlock() != HAL_OK)
  {
    return FLASHIF_CRCKO;
  } 
uint32_t i ;
 status = FLASHIF_OK;
 
  /* DataLength must be a multiple of 32 bit */
  for ( i = 0U; (i < (length >> 2U)) && (destination <= (USER_FLASH_END_ADDRESS - 4U)); i++) //
  {

    /* Device voltage range supposed to be [2.7V to 3.6V], the operation will
       be done by word */


    if (HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, (destination + (i * 4U)), *(uint32_t *)(p_source + i)) == HAL_OK)
    {

      /* Check the written value */
      if (*(__IO uint32_t *)(destination + (i * 4U)) != *(uint32_t *)(p_source + i))
      {
        status = FLASHIF_WRITINGCTRL_ERROR;
      }

        /* Increment FLASH destination address */
//       destination += 4;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Error occurred while writing data in Flash memory */
      status = FLASHIF_WRITING_ERROR;
      break;
    }
//  SerialPrint(" 4 \n");

    if (status != FLASHIF_OK)
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  /* Lock the Flash to disable the flash control register access (recommended
     to protect the FLASH memory against possible unwanted operation) *********/
  
  halErrorFlag = HAL_FLASH_Lock();
  if( halErrorFlag != HAL_OK)
  {
  } 
 
  
  return status;
}
```

I suspect with `blockData` type `uint8_t` array and `FLASH_If_Write` requires 32 bit. But how can I solve this, or is this my problem? I don't know.

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129064/flash-if-write-and-hardfault

Comment: The next time you try to debug this code, try setting the `USAGEFAULTENA`, `BUSFAULTENA`, and `MEMFAULTENA` bits in the `SCB->SHCSR` register. What this will do is give you separate fault interrupts for all these various different errors instead of lumping them all together as a generic HardFault. Now you'll have a better idea of where the root cause of the problem could be when one of these occurs, for example if it's a MemFault then the code probably tried to read or write an invalid address, or if it's a UsageFault then maybe the read or write was incorrectly aligned, etc ...

Comment: Please try debugging line by line, check the addresses. You are probably trying to write data to an address outside the border.